# Web app and RESTful webservices using same classes

Tags: rest, web-services, spring-boot

Here is how my web app is organized:

```
pom.xml
project.repository
    -> pom.xml
    -> FooRepository.java
    -> BarRepository.java
project.service
    -> pom.xml
    -> FooService.java
    -> BarService.java
    -> project.service.impl
           -> FooServiceImpl.java
           -> BarServiceImpl.java
project.web
    -> pom.xml
    -> MainApplication.java
```

Now, I would like to introduce multiple RESTful services (independant from each other). Each one would be launched on a different port. But each one would use same ressources as my current web app (services, repository, ...).

How could I do that? Same project? Multiple projects?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run your RESTful services on different ports, 
then i would suggest use Multiple Projects and IF you want to run all RESTful services on same Port then you can use Same project.